# Regex test of weird parentheses（）?

Tags: javascript, regex, ascii

So I have this character that popped up on a file that was uploaded on my website: （）

The thing is, they're not normal brackets. These brackets have spaces in them, in one character.

How do I replace them with normal parenthesis in Javascript? i.e.: ()

Comment: They are called full-width parentheses.

Comment: What language do you want to use?

Comment: @MarkTolonen I am mostly coding in javascript, so javascript would be fine.

Comment: @Sweeper I've been scouring the internet on what they are. Apparently, they're not parenthesis with spaces. LOL. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: `
 var str = "( )";
 str = str.replace(" ","");
`